# Spring integration Java DSL : creating jms Message Driver Channel Adapter

Tags: spring-integration

I'm having issues with the following Message Driver Channel Adapter

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow jmsInboundFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.messageDriverChannelAdapter(this.jmsConnectionFactory)
                .outputChannel(MessageChannels.queue("inbound").get())
                .destination("test"))   
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow channelFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("inbound")
                .transform("hello "::concat)
                .handle(System.out::println)
                .get();
    }
```

I'm getting an error about "Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel".  What's the preferred configuration for sending the message payload to another integration flow?

Comment: Do you have `@EnableIntegration` defined on one of your `@Configuration` classes?

Comment: I do have @EnableIntegration defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With that Java DSL `channel auto-creation` you should be careful. For example that `.outputChannel(MessageChannels.queue("inbound").get())` doesn't populate a `MessageChannel` bean to the bean factory. But from other side `IntegrationFlows.from("inbound")` does that.

To fix your issue I suggest to extract `@Bean` for your `inbound` channel, or just rely on the DSL:

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.messageDriverChannelAdapter(this.jmsConnectionFactory)
            .destination("test"))
            .channel(MessageChannels.queue("inbound").get())   
            .get();
```

Feel free to raise a GH-issue to fix JavaDocs on that `.outputChannel()` or remove it alltogether, since it is confused.

Comment: This is what I had before with the .channel.  Then I noticed the .outputChannel configuration so that's why I switched.  So it's differently confusing.

Comment: When you say just rely on the DSL I'm not sure I understand.  For example, how would I wire up the error channel?

Comment: A `error-channel` represents a separate message flow, so it should be based on the real `MessageChannel` `@Bean`.